# functions that produce lists of lists in scheme

Tags: function, list, scheme, boolean

I'm trying to use scheme to write a function `f` that takes a number `n` and a function `g` and returns a list of lists of length `n`, but according with booleans according to the pattern indicated by `g`. For example, the function `f` should take n say 3 and the function `g` which makes every 3rd item on the list a true. It should return this:

```
(list (list true true false)
      (list true true false)
      (list true true false))
```

I have no idea where to start with this, so any help or tips would be greatly appreciated. THanks!

Comment: The problem is under-specified and ambiguous. Say the desired function is (f n g). What arguments does g take? Is `(f n g)` of length `n`, or are the elements of `(f n g)` of length `n`, or are all lists of length `n`?

Answer (score 1):

Key to this looks like using `map`.

In short, `map` takes a function and a list, and applies the function to that list, returning the modified list.

To do this, as I'm assuming you don't want a direct solution, I'd first construct your list of lists (just use an accumulator -- count down -- to make the list as long as needed, and use `cons` and `list` and `quote` for everything else.

Then simply apply map (probably twice, depending on how you implement your solution) to the list of lists. (eg list `l` and function `fn`: `(map fn (car l))` and recur with the `cdr` of `l` and `cons` the results back together).

Good luck! Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite follow what you're trying to do, but in addition to `map`, you might find `build-list` to be useful.  `build-list` takes a number and a procedure, takes the range from 0 to that number less 1, and maps your procedure over that range.  e.g.

```
> (build-list 5 (lambda (x) (* x x)))
(0 1 4 9 16)
```